# При заполнении массива: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. При заполнении массива, возникает ошибка "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта".
Вот код:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();    
doc.LoadXml(xml);
string[][] mas = new string[doc.GetElementsByTagName("xml").Count][];
for (int i = 0; i < doc.GetElementsByTagName("xml").Count; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < doc.GetElementsByTagName("xml")[i].ChildNodes.Count; j++)
        mas[i][j] = doc.GetElementsByTagName("xml")[i].ChildNodes[j].InnerText;
```

При дебаге проверяю, `doc.GetElementsByTagName("xml")[i].ChildNodes[j].InnerText` не null. В чем может быть проблема? Массив создавал разными способами, и так как сейчас, и `string[,] mas = new string[,] {};` Массив не известного размера, точнее количество `doc.GetElementsByTagName("xml")` не известно заранее.

Comment: Извиняюсь, опечатался в вопросе. Уже просто сил нет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

у вас `null` `mas[i]`. это jagged array, мало создать "массив массивов", нужно еще и вручную создать каждый вложенный массив:

```
string[][] mas = new string[doc.GetElementsByTagName("xml").Count][];
for (int i = 0; i < doc.GetElementsByTagName("xml").Count; i++)
{
    mas[i] = new string[doc.GetElementsByTagName("xml")[i].ChildNodes.Count];
    for (int j = 0; j < doc.GetElementsByTagName("xml")[i].ChildNodes.Count; j++)
    {
        mas[i][j] = doc.GetElementsByTagName("xml")[i].ChildNodes[j].InnerText;
    }
}
```

А еще ваш код делает выборку из doc много-много раз. и Его можно заменить на

```
string[][] mas = doc.GetElementsByTagName("xml").Cast<XmlNode>()
            .Select(x => x.ChildNodes.Cast<XmlNode>().Select(n => n.InnerText).ToArray())
            .ToArray();
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Такая глупая ошибка...

Comment: @Adept22 попробуйте через linq. он намного облегчает работу с коллекциями.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо еще раз. Попробую

Answer (score 2):

Намного проще работать с человеческими структурами данных и LINQ. И переходите на современный `XDocument`.

```
var data = XDocument.Parse(xml)
                    .Descendants("xml")
                    .Select(el => el.Elements()
                                    .Select(child => child.Value)
                                    .ToList())
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Проще - да, но вот производительнее ли ?

Comment: @Fabjan: Ну выиграете вы на неудобных структурах данных 2 микросекунды, ну так по сравнению со временем на разбор XML это ноль. Зато потеряете удобство отладки и написания программы. Смысл?

Comment: Думаю здесь все будет зависеть от конкретной ситуации, если говорить о данном примере, скорее всего вы правы.

Comment: @Fabjan: Ситуации, в которых надо отказаться от удобного инструмента в пользу производительности, очень редки. В любом случае, надо сначала спрофилировать и понять, что просадка производительности именно там, где вы собираетесь править. Затем попробовать улучшить алгоритмы и структуры данных. И только если это не удастся, ухудшать код. Преждевременная оптимизация — источник всех бед.